# Open dialogue box on <div> click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My site pages run off `header.php`, which contains all the JavaScript and CSS needed for all the pages.

What I am trying to do is make it so that, whatever page a user is on, if they click the `<div>` `.register_button_click`, they will have a JavaScript dialogue box open up. I have placed the JavaScript in the header.php file and have created my `<div class="register_button_click">click here</div>`, but it's not bringing anything up.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<head>       
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var $dialog; 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('My Dialog Demo...')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'My Dialog'
            });

            $('#register_button_click').click(function () {
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                return false; ////cancel eventbubbeling
            });
        });

        function showDialog() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false //cancel eventbubbeling
        }

    </script>
 </head>
```

Comment: Your question says `.register_button_click` but the code says `#register...`  and you have a `showDialog` method that is never called.

Comment: access elements through class by $('.className') and not otherwise

Comment: Are you are creating the div dinamically? in that case the event won't be binded and you need to use jQuery live or similar http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Mc- Don't point people to `live` as it is deprecated.  Point them to the "event delegation" section of the `on` documentation.

Comment: Wops, totally right @JamesMontagne

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change from an id to a class:

```
           $('.register_button_click').click(function () {
               showDialog();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the jquery function you are trying to access the element by it's ID. But you only have defined the element's class in the HTML code.

Change your div to `<div id="register_button_click">click here</div>` and everything is gonna be ok.